# Which Ruby REST API client for neo4j?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, neo4j

I wonder what the REST API clients are available for using from Ruby (not JRuby, so native bindings are not an option)?

Ideally, I would want the API similar to the `neo4j` gem or `ActiveRecord` (validations, migrations, observers etc).

Currently available (REST) tooling doesn't even come close to what we have, for example, in ActiveRecrod:

1. [neograhy](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography) - just **plain REST** API. Nothing to do with models etc.
2. [neology](https://github.com/lordkada/neology) - is just a **wrapper over neography** and isn't a full featured ActiveModel.
3. [architect4r](https://github.com/namxam/architect4r) - **conforms to ActiveModel**, but provides only one way to query data ([Cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-query-lang.html) language), also no indexes support.

I like the code of `architect4r` a little bit more (primarily because it uses ActiveModel).

But `neology` seems to be much more pragmatic choice as it already is using `neography` under the hood.

The choice is pretty small and tough.

Could you please tell when one should be used rather than the other?
Also any recommendations that would help me to decide on the gem are very welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no any mature ActiveModel-like gems for RESTful neo4j.

The most common scenario is to just use Neography.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with neoj yet, but i do work with api's a lot.

I have found the same trouble as you and my solution was to create my own.

Maybe if you have time, you can check it out. [ApiClient](https://github.com/zertico/api-client/)

It still in development, so let me know of any feature you may need. =)

Answer (score 1):

I have only used Neography which does its job very well. Have not heard about architect4r, but it looks really pragmatic and pleasing - need to check it out!

/peter

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a little old, but there is activity on the neo4j-core gem geared towards using its API for the standalone database server in addition to the embedded database.  Thought this might help people who find this thread when searching around.

https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j-core/tree/3.0

Note:  Before anyone yells at me for not making this a comment instead of an answer, I don't have the required reputation for doing so.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at REST-Client?  https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client

it seems like it might be a very easy to to create and examine the responses from calls to a REST API.   but maybe you need more than that?

(I was searching for answers and found your question, so far rest-client seems like the top candidate for what I need, figured it might help you also.

Comment: Neography works better than rest-client as it is tailored for neo4j. Neither of the gems support any kind of ActiveModel and are compliant with it.

Comment: ok so then `"but maybe you need more than that" == true` it seems

Comment: Yeah, of course it's true. I think I explained it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is also activerecord-neo4j-adapter, but I have no experience with it.

https://github.com/digitalbias/activerecord-neo4j-adapter

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Keymaker](https://github.com/therubymug/keymaker), which provides ActiveModel support for Neo4j.
Problem is, docs are non-existent, so you have to search out slideshows/presentations to find actual examples.