# Neo4j with Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j

I created a ruby on rails web app which I deployed on heroku, by following this guide

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

The app is very similar to this tutorial in that a user can create an account, log in, create an object with some information which is belongs to that user. These objects I created are meant to represent nodes which I would like to be able to create relationships between.

I have been reading up on Neo4j and it seems like the best fit for ruby but then I read that it only really works with JRuby. Could anyone tell me would it work with my implementation and if so , how? or if it dosent, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JRuby allows Ruby to access Neo4j directly through the Java API. It is the fastest implementation possible. However, Neo4j also provides a REST API that allows any language to access it over HTTP.

I seems like your answer may be here: [Which Ruby REST API client for neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335136/which-ruby-rest-api-client-for-neo4j)

Answer (score 1):

This is again using the Neography gem, but this blog maxdemarzi has got some really nice posts on integrating ruby with neo4j.

Here's a link: http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/01/04/getting-started-with-ruby-and-neo4j/

But as mentioned by others, I don't think you'd get anything that can talk directly to the Java API other than JRuby.